# android studio show gibberish when I commit through git

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github

[image]

When I commit changes through git, Android Studio shows the gibberish tip. Could you please help me to solve this problem?
English tip is correct, but Chinese Characters are abnormal.

Excuse me, my English isn't very well, but I still need your help. I hope you could understand my question, thanks!

Comment: why is this a problem?

Comment: well, I think it just disturbs my mood whenever I am commit changes.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the language set is not supported by the IDE. Please refer below to modify the settings
[Android Studio language settings](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/translations-editor.html)

Comment: thank you! I have solved the problem by change the IDE UI font.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I found Settings-Appearance&behavior-appearance-UI Option, and uncheck the override default fonts by(not recommended), the problem is solved.